# How to get CPU usage in flash?

Tags: actionscript, air, cpu-usage

I tried to find out but Google didn't help. Is there some way to get the cpu usage in flash or adobe AIR?

I'm using ActionScript 3.0 and flash CS5.

Comment: I found an undocumented API flash.system.System.processCPUUsage():Number but when I use it it returns 0. I'm wondering if it's a release build only API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flash, there is no way. In AIR, only native helper could do it. Flash platform has tough time with system programming, it's not its strength.

Comment: That's not in AIR, that's in native program for your target platform(s). Here is C++ example for Windows: http://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/cpuusageByDudiAvramov.aspx. AIR can call that exe with NativeProcess and read stdout.