# The AIR application not responding after some time

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air

I have Adobe AIR application that uses many swc's, i facing a blocker that when user dont interact with my AIR application more then half an hour and when user return back, the application not responding, i aslo try backgroundFramerate=-1, but no avail, please help me any one...

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the Profiler and see what's going on. Flash Builder has a built in profile that will monitor the application. Run the profile and watch the graphs and it will help you isolate a memory leak or other issues. Here's some documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7e46.html

If you don't have Flash Builder you can also get some debugging information and display it. Check this post: [Is it possible to profile CPU / memory inside an Adobe AIR application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539504/is-it-possible-to-profile-cpu-memory-inside-an-adobe-air-application)

Comment: thanks Jonathan Rowny, i already run profiler. actually the problem found in repeater control, now i use DataGroup instead of repeater and i m happy to find the soloution...